# Using coveringGrid function in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I've just started having a play about with the new `coveringGrid()` geometry function in Earth Engine but it seems to be exhibiting some strange behaviour.

When I run it for a feature, the result shows up correctly in the map, though when I try to use the result for subsequent operations there are features missing from the grid.

I've attached a link to the script highlighting it, where the black feature is the original shapefile input, the blue feature is the result of the `coveringGrid()` function and what is visualised in in the Map in Earth Engine (i.e. the expected result), and the yellow feature is what is subsequently seen by GEE (cribbed by using `getInfo()`).

Code sample and link below:

```
var RGIRegion='03'
var RGIpath='users/Jmleaglacio/RGI7alpha/RGI'+RGIRegion;
var RGIsimplifiedPath='users/Jmleaglacio/RGI7alpha/RGI'+RGIRegion+'_simplified1km';

// The input Feature
var RGIsimplified=ee.Feature(ee.FeatureCollection(RGIsimplifiedPath).first()).aside(print);

Map.addLayer(RGIsimplified)
//There are 22 blue squares, but only 12 are shown by the print statement
var RGIgridInitial=ee.FeatureCollection(ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Feature(RGIsimplified).geometry()
                .coveringGrid('EPSG:3857',1000000))).aside(print)
                
print(RGIgridInitial)
Map.addLayer(RGIgridInitial,{color:'blue'}) //the expected result
Map.addLayer(ee.FeatureCollection(RGIgridInitial.getInfo()),{color:'yellow'}) //the actual result
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7ba22d963850a6134e92bcc50b8d5466

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: the issue was that the input feature collection was in a different projection to the projection I defined in the `coveringGrid()` function. If you're using this function, make sure to use `ee.Algorithms.projectionTransform()` on the input feature collection to make sure that the crs of the input is the same as the one defined in `coveringGrid()`. Link to code with correct solution here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/05bcb880dc058b653f0ce2483c39d8ec

Comment: Please share your FeatureCollection `users/Jmleaglacio/RGI7alpha/RGI03_simplified1km` so others can run your linked code.